# The Shortest Distance between Oriented Bounding Boxes

Tags: geometry, collision-detection, unreal

This is the problem that I am facing. Given two oriented bounding boxes (8 vertex, center, extent), I want to get the shortest distance between boxes.

Specifically, I have two vehicle objects moving which lies in 3D, and the bounding box should be considered whether they will collide at some points, then I want to track the shortest distance between them while playing.

I do know that there is SAT (Separating Axis Theorem) & GJK Algorithm whether they collide or not, but how would I be able to get the shortest distance between boxes?

Comment: Hi, interesting question! How are you defining the shortest distance between the boxes? Do you need the shortest distance between any point on either box's perimeter, or just  the shortest distance between the closest vertices?

Comment: For the 'exact' case, the approach is given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3232521/shortest-distance-between-two-rectangles-in-2d

Comment: You can look at `rotating calipers` (it is one of standard applications of RC approach)

Comment: @gremto. I would say that it's the shortest distance between any point on the box perimeter!

Answer (score 0):

SAT states that for two disjoint convex sets you can find a direction such that there is a plane orthogonal to it which separates the two sets. We can rephrase it to "you can find a direction such that if you project both sets onto it, they will form non-intersecting intervals".

While SAT talks about *any* direction, in its proof the special direction is used - the direction of the line between the closest points. It can be proved that this direction provides the best separation which means the distance between those intervals is maximal (and equal to the distance between sets).
[image]

While it can be hard to get that direction immediately from box geometry, it's possible to list a finite number of candidates.

So the algorithm is the following:

1. enumerate all candidates for the best separating direction
2. measure separation along each of them
3. get the maximum

The surface of a box can be divided into three sets:

1. vertices (corners)
2. edges (except vertices)
3. faces (except vertices and edges)

So we can ask "where does the first point fall?" and then "where does the second one fall?". This gives us 9 options. For every option we get some candidates for the separating direction (assuming we are talking about the closest pair of points):

1. vertex-vertex

   - that's just the direction between two points
   - so 8*8=64 candidates
2. vertex-edge

   - if the closest point is on the edge interior, then we need the direction of projection of the vertex onto the line of the edge, which is `edge.direction.cross(vertex-edge.point).cross(edge.direction)`
   - that gives us 8*12=96 candidates
3. vertex-face

   - in this case it has to be the face's normal
   - that gives us 8*6=48 candidates
4. edge-vertex

   - the same as #2, but the boxes are swapped
   - +96 candidates
5. edge-edge

   - here it has to be orthogonal to both lines, so it's `edge1.direction.cross(edge2.direction)`
   - 12*12=144 candidates
6. edge-face

   - that's an interesting one
   - if the closest points lie on an edge and a face, that means the edge is parallel to the face (otherwise we could move the points to reduce the distance)
   - that means that moving the points synchronously along the edge direction doesn't change anything
   - so we can move them until hit either a face's edge/vertex or an edge's vertex
   - which means that no new candidates are needed for this case
7. face-vertex

   - same as #3
   - +48 candidates
8. face-edge

   - same as #6
   - 0 candidates
9. face-face

   - using the same reasoning as in #6, we can see that no candidates are needed for this case

That gives 496 candidates to check.

But since we are talking about boxes, which have lots of parallel edges and faces, there are a lot of duplicates here:

1. vertex-vertex: no optimisations here, it still can give 64 candidates
2. vertex-edge: again, 96 candidates
3. vertex-face: just 3, since there are only 3 different face normals
4. edge-vertex: 96, as in #2
5. edge-edge: 9 (3 different directions from one box, 3 from another)
6. face-vertex: 3, as in #3

271 in total, I suspect other optimisations may be possible, but they need to be simple enough to not over weigh the cost of simple checking of the direction.